# Documentation for Matter Standard? ... Github project exists, but no overview

Tags: google-smart-home, matter-iot-standard

The Matter standard will important for the connected home.  So, I want to understand the technical details.

A relatively active Github project is here: https://github.com/project-chip/connectedhomeip but where is the summary document/standard to help explain the code?  It seems like the code must be written to some specification.

Answer (score 1):

Matter is still new and many onboarding materials are still under active development. The best place you can start from will be the example projects under [connectedhomeip](https://github.com/project-chip/connectedhomeip). For example, you can take a look at [lighting app](https://github.com/project-chip/connectedhomeip/tree/master/examples/lighting-app).

Once you get the right development board from one of those manufacturers, click on the corresponding project from the list and follow the instructions.

Answer (score 0):

Check this guide: https://developers.home.google.com/matter

Or maybe even better this one: https://developers.home.google.com/samples/matter-app

Regarding the specification itself, I think you must be a CSA member to access it.